# Can you point clang-format to a .clang-format file that is in a sub-dir?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

We have lots of c++ code repos in our project and generally they are structured like this:

```
some_sw_repo/
    |
    |-- tools/ (sub-module, common to all projects)
          |
          |-- .clang-format
```

I run clang-format at the `some_sw_repo/` folder level, but I can't see any way to tell clang-format that the `.clang-format` file is in the `tools/` sub-folder. So currently I am copying the format file up and then running clang-format and then deleting it again (since I don't want the local copy - we want one copy for all projects).

This is ok, because I can add a make recipe to do this. However there is also a really handy vs-code addon: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format

Which works really well... if the .clang-format file is in the top level.

Is there any way at all to tell clang-format that the .clang-format file is in a specific place?

My version of clang-format is v10.0.0

Comment: [doesn't look like there is an option to do that](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)

Comment: There's no way to do that currently afaik. The workaround you have seems reasonable enough.

Comment: oh shame - thanks both : )